# ValueError: unknown url type: h

Tags: python, urllib2

I wrote an application in python to download the file at a specified hour but I received **ValueError: unknown url type: h** Error
this is my code

```
import time,os,urllib2
coun=input("Enter count of the movies:")
x=0
namelist=[]
addresslist=[]
os.chdir('D:\\')
while(coun > x):
    name=raw_input("Enter the name of movie:")
    namelist.append(name)
    address=raw_input("enter the address of %s:"%(name))
    addresslist.append(address)
    x=x+1
ti= time.localtime().tm_hour
print('it\'s wating...')
while(ti!=11):
    ti= time.localtime().tm_hour
    timi=time.localtime().tm_min
    tisec=time.localtime().tm_sec
    if (ti==3 & timi==59 & tisec==59):
        print('it\'s 3')
print('it\'s your time.let start downloating')
x=0
while(coun > x):
    data=urllib2.urlopen(address[x])
    file=open(namelist[x],'wb')
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    x=x+1
```

And when I run it and answer the questions that return to me this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tidopy.py", line 24, in <module>
    data=urllib2.urlopen(address[x])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 421, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 283, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: h
```

**How can I fix it?**
  please help

Comment: Triple check what the variable `address` is! It's a string, so `address[x]` is a single character.

Comment: You probably meant to use `addresslist`, and not `address`.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
data=urllib2.urlopen(address[x])
```

Should most likely be this:

```
data=urllib2.urlopen(addresslist[x])
```

You want the element of the list `addresslist`, not the first character of the string `address`.

Comment: thanks alot. I didn't focus on that sorry!